# Css Pseudo-class :first-letter

Tags: html, css

Can it be used inside an `a` tag?

```
a.x:first-letter
{
   color:red;
}
```

My name is `<a class=x>Lionel</a>`

I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: I'm sorry? Didn't quite get what you meant.

Comment: you need to accept answers when they satisfy your questions.

Comment: oh ok.got what you mean. Didn't know it works like this. Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should work fine.

Can you provide a JSFiddle example of it not working?

It certainly should work -- See [here for a test page which demonstrates it in action](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstline.html), and [here for a browser compatibility chart](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) (it says it should work in any browser).

[EDIT]

As @SilentGhost says, it only works for block level elements, which `<p>` is and `<a>` isn't.

You can make inline elements like `<a>` act as block elements by using the `display:block;` style. However this can mess up your page layout.

Fortunately, there is a half-way house option: `display:inline-block;` which should make your element get treated as a block element without disrupting your page layout. Try adding that to your stylesheet as follows:

```
a.x {
  display:block;
}
```

Your `:first-letter` style should now work.

Answer (score 5):

According to css2.1 `:first-letter` applies only to [block container elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-CSS2-20101207/selector.html#first-letter).

Comment: errmmm .... what is a block container elements? so that means it doesnt work with the <a> tag? is there any fast solution to my question ? thanks in advance

Comment: @lionel: I linked to the the spec that has further explanation. By default `a` is **not** a block container element.

Comment: interesting. I didn't know that. So therefore, you could probably get it to work by doing `display:inline-block;`...? Not that I've really had much need of `first-letter`, so I haven't played with it that much. Interesting that it seems to work for `<p>` which also isn't a block type element.

Comment: @Spudley: of course `p` is block type element, what are you talking about? `first-letter` and `first-line` are intended for typographical manipulation of corresponding elements of a paragraph. Yes, it will work for any `inline-block` as well.

Comment: eh, yes, I was being dense with `<p>` - of course it is. (don't worry; I was thinking of something else). The important thing about using the `inline-block` solution is that it should solve the problem without changing the layout of the element (whereas `display:block;` would do).